# What type of neural network for non-classficable problems

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I am new at machine learning, and I am trying to build a network which will not predict a label for the given input. Instead it should guess the outcome in a range of values, for example:

```
a_old = [5.5, 3.4 , 1.1] , x = 1.732 , y = 2.223 , z = -1.444 
=======> a_new = [6.6 , 5.1, 0.9]
```

The network should predict a_new, but a_new is a three dim-vector and its value-range is huge, therefore I cannot just create 10^15 different labels to classify it.

Which type of neural network do I need for this kind of problems. Is it even possible?

Comment: That is called regression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose any architecture for your network and then use linear activation function as an output + mean squared error loss. E.g:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(150, input_dim=n, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(30, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizers.adam(lr=0.01))
```

Answer (score 1):

While the comment by @josef morgen makes more sense , if you want to do this via a neural network , there is no reason why shouldn't be able to , a neural doesn't actually print labels , it prints values for each class and we max them to get a predicted label (  I am talking about the case of simple classification tasks)

A node of a neural network is actually much like a regression classifier and hence a dense network is alble to learn a much more complex function unlike regression

For you particular case I suggest you take your data in the same format and use mean squared error as your loss . It should work